# Loop performance issues

Tags: windev

I was facing performance issues with a simple WinDev application with a couple of nested 'for' loops that iterate about 7 million times.

This simple application took around 30 seconds to finish in WinDev but only about 10 milliseconds in Java or C++ (yes, I am sure it's the same app).

After many tries I just made a simple 'for' loop to iterate 180 million times in both Java and WinDev and I am now concerned about the general performance of WinDev. This is the simple program:

```
dtStartDate = SysDateTime()
myCount is int = 0
mySize is int = 180000000
FOR i = 1 _TO_ mySize
       myCount++
END
dtFinalDate = SysDateTime()
dDiferenciaCalculada = dtFinalDate - dtStartDate
UpdateDebugOutput("time: " + dDiferenciaCalculada..InMilliseconds + "; myCount: " + myCount)
RETURN
```

In my computer this 'for' loop takes around 5000 milliseconds to complete in Windev but only 60 milliseconds in Java.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

**--- UPDATE 20170524 ---**

The real application I was testing is next:

WinDev app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vm0yrfcb3wc46r/TestProject.zip?dl=0

Java app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j896r3pl5kh2iit/playground_java.zip?dl=0

It's a simple app that reads a file, makes some basic calculation and fills some objects of an array with that data. The WindDev app is taking around 27 seconds and the Java app only a few milliseconds and I don't know how to speed up the process in WinDev.

Could you propose some alternatives to my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Windev is not the fastest, and by far. But you don't choose Windev because of this. The utilisation of Parallel functions could clearly speed up your program in this case.

**Update 24/05/2017 - 09:24**

My bad, Windev follows more or less the C# language evolutions but they didn't implement the C# [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx).
If you really want to speed up your work and you work on Windows only you can use a .Net library which do the dirty work of your function and use the `Parallel.For` that you call from your application. [Windev works pretty smoothly with .Net Library.](http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?7512001)

**Update 24/05/2017 - 10:58**
And of course I haven't share the correct link : http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?2012002

Comment: Thanks @Bidjes, could you elaborate a little bit your answer? I have also updated my original post with the exact case I am facing to.

Comment: I understand I can execute WLanguage code from an external language app (Java for example but the same for your link in C#: http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?7515001&name=external_language_programming_java) but I need the opposite, I have the entire app written in WLanguage and I have to invoke some external Java/C# routine to make the dirty job. How can I invoke this external task from my main WLanguage app (the real scenario is a large WLanguage app, not just the simple project I uploaded)

Comment: Ok I'll take a look to that but I am not very experienced in .NET. If I finally had to do something like that I think I'll try to do something with an external Java app. Thank you for your comments.